# Spring - Inconsistent context path

Tags: spring, url, relative-path

Spring seems to resolve links in an inconsistent way.
For example, if the current URL is

```
http://localhost/roles
```

the following anchor

```
<a href="roleA1">roleA1</a>
```

goes to http://localhost/roleA1 instead of http://localhost/roles/roleA1

On the other hand, if the current URL is

```
http://localhost/roles/    (note the '/' at the end)
```

the previous link will resolve to http://localhost/roles/roleA1

Both http://localhost/roles and http://localhost/roles/ go to the same page, so Spring treats them equally. Now I would like to avoid using absolute paths but if I leave it as it is now, users navigating to http://localhost/roles will get the wrong behaviour.

Is there a way to fix it?

This is my Controller's configuration:

```
@RequestMapping("/roles")
public class RoleController {

  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String roles(final Map<String, Object> model) {
    ...

    return "roles";
  }

  @RequestMapping(path = "/{roleId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String role(@PathVariable String roleId, final Map<String, Object>  model) {
    ...

    return "role";
  }
```

Comment: I think your context path is `/roles` am I right ? If not then you need to give full url in anchor tag.

Comment: @sunkuet02 does my edit answer your question?

Comment: spring servlet always maps the url from the root context path. Check spring-servlet-dispather